# How to output Unicode characters from hex string in C++?

Tags: c++, unicode, hex

I have a string called `str` containing the hex code `265A` and I would like to output it as a Unicode character, which should be the black chess king.

So these are the ways I have already tried:

```
std::string str = "\u" + str;
std::cout << str;
```

but this gives me the error

```
error: incomplete universal character name \u
```

Doing

```
std::cout << "\u" << str;
```

also didn't work, for the same reason.

So I tried using `wchar_t` like this:

```
wchar_t wc = strtol(str.c_str(), NULL, 16);
std::wcout << wc;
```

but that just didn't output anything.

So I really don't know what else to do.

Comment: In which encoding do you want it?

Comment: The first two don't work because `\u` is a compile-time operation, not a runtime operation. You need to provide more information on what happens in the third case. What is the value of `wc`? Is it possible that your `wcout` simply doesn't support that character?

Comment: Huh, I have not thought aout that. I tried encoding with UTF8 now and in Windows I just get weird characters when doing `std::cout << "\u265A"`, namely `â™š`. I'll have to read a bit into this. But some encoding that works on Windows. @Biffen

Comment: Well, the problem is, that I don't know any other way of checking the value of `wc`, other that `std::wcout`, but the documentation of `strtol` suggests it should do what it is supposed to do. Also what do you mean, by not able to output? 265A is pretty high up, so that might be a possibility, but how do I bypass it? @RaymondChen

Comment: @kim366 have you considered that perhaps your console does not support UTF-8?

Comment: Try using a debugger. The default locale for `wcout` in Windows is the "C" locale, which as I recall does not support characters above 255.

Comment: it does. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955385/utf-8-in-windows-7-cmd @user2079303

Comment: Thank you! I did use a debugger and it said "Expression expected" (my translation), so I will look into that.

Comment: @kim366 What are you talking about? Back then you didn't even know what a debugger was..

Answer (score 1):

Your `strtol` approach is about right.  The following test program tests that you can create an `A` this way:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string str = "41";

    wchar_t wc = std::strtol(str.c_str(), NULL, 16);
    std::wcout << wc << std::endl;
}
```

You're likely having problems with the output side of things, or your system's `wchar_t` is some non-Unicode type - you can demonstrate that with something like

```
std::wcout << wchar_t(65) << wchar_t(0x265A) << std::endl;
```