# Python 3.5.2 - help()-function not showing å,ä,ö (UTF-8 characters) correct

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding

In the `help()` function, characters like å, ä, ö are not showing correct. See following code and screenshot:

```
def my_function():
    '''
    Här är en överdriven kommentar, å, ä, ö
    '''
    print("Här är en överdriven kommentar, å, ä, ö")

help(my_function)
my_function()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Anyone knows why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually a CMD *issue* rather than Python. If you'd run this in an IDE like PyCharm, you'll get the expected result:

> ```
> Help on function my_function in module __main__:
>
> my_function()
>     Här är en överdriven kommentar, å, ä, ö
>
> Här är en överdriven kommentar, å, ä, ö
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

Have a look at the following topics related to this subject:

- **[Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how)**
- **[UTF-8 in Windows 7 CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955385/utf-8-in-windows-7-cmd)**
- **[Windows cmd encoding change causes Python crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878972/windows-cmd-encoding-change-causes-python-crash/3259271)**